# dynamic checkbox creation

Tags: java, android, dynamic, checkbox

I am wanting to create a set of checkboxes dynamically during run time in my android application. When the application runs nothing shows up except the button. What am i forgetting? Thanks in advance!

```
public class DataNotificationSurvey extends Activity {
    private Date timeStamp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.datanotifylayout);
        final Button notifySubmitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notifySubmitButton);
        TableLayout t1 = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.notificationTableLayout);

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            CheckBox chk = new CheckBox(this);
            chk.setText(Integer.toString(i));
            tr.addView(chk);
            t1.addView(tr);
        }

        notifySubmitButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
}
```

---

```
//My xml layout, will be changing this later to the one posted below to see if it works.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/notificationLinearLayout"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/notificationTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <Button android:text="Static Button"/>
        </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
  <Button
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/notifySubmitButton"
  android:text="Submit"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your layout.xml as well... the code looks okay, so the problem may be there.

Comment: @harpo: added the xml, i will be changing later to reflect the xml that is posted as an answer. If it works, i will let you know. However, if you see a problem in the xml or anywhere else, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me.

```
public class DynamicTableRowWithCheckBox extends Activity
{
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final Button notifySubmitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.myTable);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
      TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
      CheckBox chk = new CheckBox(this);
      chk.setText(Integer.toString(i));
      row.addView(chk);
      table.addView(row);
    }

    notifySubmitButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v)
          {
            finish();
          }
        });
  }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Close" />
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/myTable" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Will try this tomorrow and let you know results. my xml is different than yours, well be changing to see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Posted my current xml, when i get the chance i will try your xml and see what happens. However, if you see anything wrong with what i have so far, let me know. I may not get the chance to try your xml until later this evening. Thanks

Comment: What was this displaying for you? Because it just displays the two buttons for me. No rows and no string representing the "i" value in the for loop.

Comment: This xml file worked. I did not have android orientation in mine, so they were all trying to display on the same line. Just simply overlooked that feature. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Change your XML to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/notificationLinearLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/notificationTableLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow>
            <Button
                android:text="Static Button" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/notifySubmitButton"
        android:text="Submit"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

This removes the layout_height of your TableLayout to wrap_content, and it removes the height and width settings of your TableRow, because, ["The children of a TableRow do not need to specify the layout_width and layout_height attributes in the XML file. TableRow always enforces those values to be respectively MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT."](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html)

Comment: This still does not display the rows like i intend. It only displays the static button and the submit button. That is all it displays. I need it to display the rows too.

Comment: This xml file needs the orientation:vertical value to be set.

Comment: Ah, yes.  The default orientation for LinearLayout is horizontal.