# Edittext in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

when a user inputs a number,i need to generate that many EditText fields so the user can input data?anyone know a way to do it...

Comment: @prolink007  sorry,i have not used the account,i received the notification when i am using askubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i needed to do something very similar to this but with check boxes. Here is my question, read through it and check out the accepted answer. This helped me a lot and it should help you too.

[My Question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534357/dynamic-checkbox-creation)

Basically copy the stuff from the accepted answer and modify it for edit text boxes. You will need the xml file as well.